# Was the day when Jesus died a day of preparation for a regular Sabbath, for Passover or for both?

Tags: gospels

The Synoptics (Mark 14:12; Matt. 26:17, Luke 22:7) and John 19:31 seems to understand "preparation" differently.

As per [Discussion here](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/17255/the-meaning-of-%CF%80%CE%B1%CF%81%CE%B1%CF%83%CE%BA%CE%B5%CF%85%E1%BD%B5-day-of-preparation) holy days like Passover can still be called Sabbath even though it does not fall on Saturday. (See the answer provided by schuh)

So, when did Jesus died: on the day of preparation of Passover (Not necessarily Friday) or on the day of preparation of sabbath (Friday)?

Comment: Presumably the μεγαλη η ημερα referred to by John 19:31 ('high day' as the KJV calls it) means that the day following the death of Jesus was both the Passover _and_ a sabbath. I assume this is the crux of the question - the meaning of μεγαλη η ημερα.

Comment: Jesus died on a Wednesday before sunset and rose Saturday before sunset. Here is a video you might enjoy. https://youtu.be/EmtyYqq11Qc

Comment: @NigelJ The "great day", I believe, is the 8th and *last* day of Sukkoth, not the day *before* anything else: *[Jhn 7:37 ESV] (37) **On the last day of the feast, the great day**, Jesus stood up and cried out, "If anyone thirsts, let him come to me and drink.* Please see: http://jewishencyclopedia.com/articles/14103-sukkot-feast-of#anchor9

Comment: @Ruminator John 19:31 makes it clear that the 'high day' μεγαλη η ημερα was the day before the sabbath. Ergo, the μεγαλη η ημερα was a Friday. The great day was not only a sabbath it was also an 'high day'.

Comment: @Nigel J I do not discount the possibility that the 'high day' referred to the seventh day.

Comment: You must keep in mind that according to the Hebrew Scriptures there were seven annual holy convocations, only one of which was called a Sabbath (the day of Atonement). The fifteenth day of the first month was a holy convocation that forbade only *servile* work. The weekly Sabbath and the Day of Atonement were called Sabbaths because they forbade ALL work and work of ANY KIND. Nisan 15 was never called a Sabbath in the Hebrew Scriptures. It is, however, implicitly called a Sabbath in the Septuagint, about two or three centuries before Jesus walked the earth.

Comment: Jesus died on a Friday, the day before the Sabbath (Mark 15:42). Nisan 15 standing alone could not be reckoned as a Sabbath if the Hebrew Scriptures are your source for truth. Nisan 15 could be a Sabbath if it fell on the weekly Sabbath. Such a combination would indeed be a "great" Sabbath.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- All the most authoritative lexicons consistently state that παρασκευή (paraskeué) means the day of preparation before the weekly Sabbath, eg, BDAG, Friberg (Analytical Lexicon), Souter, Newman, W E Vine, etc.  (There are some less well-known lexicons that beg to differ.)
- "High Day" occurs only in John 19:31.  If Friday (at twilight) was the time for the Passover sacrifice, then the following day would be the first day of the feast of unleavened bread which would naturally make that Sabbath both the weekly Sabbath and an annual feast day; so naturally it would be extra special, or a "high day".
- Even in modern Greek, παρασκευή (paraskeué) still means Friday.
- παρασκευή (paraskeué) occurs in six places, Matt 27:62, Mark 15:42, Luke 23:54, John 19:14, 31, 42.  The phraseology in the synoptic Gospels make it clear that Jesus died on Friday.  John 19:31 also makes this clear unless we make a special pleading for the use of this word here.

Thus, the simplest way to understand John 19:31 is simply to say that it was the day of preparation (Friday) of Passover week.  Thus, in this case, Friday was the preparation day for both the weekly Sabbath which also fell on one of the annual festivals, which made it a special (or "high") Sabbath.  The NLT captures this well:

> It was the day of preparation, and the Jewish leaders didn’t want the
>   bodies hanging there the next day, which was the Sabbath (and a very
>   special Sabbath, because it was Passover week).  …

The HCSB also has a similar rendering:

> Since it was the preparation day, the Jews did not want the bodies to
>   remain on the cross on the Sabbath (for that Sabbath was a special
>   day).

Thus, the short answer to the question is, "both" preparation for the weekly Sabbath and the Passover celebrations.  As if to confirm this, we have the testimony of Luke 24:22 where Cleopas and his friend said, on Sunday evening, it was the third day since Jesus’ trial and crucifixion.  If Jesus had been crucified on Wednesday or Tuesday (as some assert) then it would be at least the fifth day.

The Pulpit commentary observes at John 19:31:

> The Jews therefore, because it was the preparation; that is, the day
>   before the sabbath (Mark 15:42). This note of time certainly blends
>   both the synoptists and John in the assurance that the crucifixion
>   took place on a Friday. It was also, according to the previous
>   statement, the preparation of the Passover, which, we have seen, is
>   better understood in that literal sense than in the sense of "the
>   Friday of Passover week." Consequently, there was a twofold sanctity
>   about that particular sabbath, seeing that the sabbatic rest of the
>   day following the Paschal meal coincided with the ordinary weekly
>   sabbath; (for great, or high, was the day of that sabbath) (cf. Exodus
>   12:16; Leviticus 23:7; and notes on John 13:1; 18:28; 19:14). It was a
>   "great" and "high" day in a sense far more profoundly impressive than
>   any that could be derived from the ceremonial enactments of the Hebrew
>   code. The sabbath of his rest came at length. The toil, the agony, are
>   over, the whole world is transformed during its hours into his
>   resting-place. There has been no such sabbath since the creative Word
>   rested from all his work.

Comment: You said if Friday (at twilight) was the time for the passover sacrifice then the next day would be the first day of the feast of unleavened bread. How do you explain the fact Jesus Christ and his disciples observed the passover the night before, and that Leviticus 23 explicitly says passover and the first day of unleavened bread are on different days (days which start at sunset)?

Comment: There were varying practices.  What I do know is Jesus was the Passover Lamb (John 1:29, 1 Cor 5:7)!  He was crucified on the day that normally killed the Passover.  Sunday was three days later (Luke 19:31) by inclusive reckoning.  Sabbath was therefore the high day. Now, if Jesus was to be crucified on Passover, then he had to celebrate the night BEFORE he died - quite simple really!

Comment: By your reckoning he was already dead and buried before the passover even arrived.

Comment: Not at all - he would have died about 3pm (as per John's account) and that gave time for Joseph to notice the death, ask Pilate for the body and place it in the tomb before sunset on Friday.  3 pm was the time of the afternoon sacrifice.

Comment: I am not sure but I think you meant a verse other than Luke 19:31 above. (By the way your comments about Luke 24 below were very helpful.)

Comment: My apologies, you are correct - I meant Luke 24:22 about three days later.

Comment: Passover is always considered a sabbath, regardless of the day it falls on.

Comment: Luke 24:21 states that the day of the resurrection was the third day SINCE the crucifixion. Jews counted their days inclusively so the first day since the crucifixion would be Friday, as strange as that sounds to our ears. "Today is the first day since these things were done". Furthermore, the greek word from where we get the english word "since" is apo. APO is often used inclusively throughout the New Testament. Jude 14 states Enoch was the seventh FROM (apo) Adam. Compare this with Genesis 5:1-18. Also, in Matthew 1:17 it states there were 14 generations from (apo) Abraham to David.

Comment: Apo is used inclusively in other places in the New Testament, like "beginning from (apo) the last unto the first" and "from (apo) the sixth hour" and "death reigned from (apo) Adam to Moses" and so forth. See Matthew 20:8, Matthew 27:35 (compare Mark 15:33), Romans 5:14. Also, if you read Acts 10:1-30 carefully, noting verses 1-7 for the first day, verses 9-22 for the second day, 23 for the third day, and 24-30 for the fourth day, you will see even the Romans counted days inclusively. There were four days in the count yet in verse 30 it was four days ago (from [apo]) this.

Answer (score 3):

It's amusing to see all the hoops some jump through to avoid a plain contradiction between gospels.

According to Mark, the gospel considered earliest, Jesus eats the Passover meal with his disciples in the evening, and is arrested that night. In the morning, he is put on trial and quickly crucified (Mark 15).

According to John, the gospel considered latest, Jesus also has a last supper with his disciples, and is crucified the next day. Which day? The day of Preparation for the Passover, when the lambs were slaughtered (John 19:14).

Why would the John gospel have Jesus crucified a day earlier? Bart Ehrman points out that John is the only gospel where Jesus is called "the lamb of God who takes away the sins of the world" (John 1:29), and again "Behold, the Lamb of God!" (John 1:36). For John, Jesus is the sacrificial lamb. So having him crucified on the same day the lambs were slaughtered makes more theological "sense".

A related issue concerns the time of day of the crucifixion. Mark 15:25 has Jesus crucified at "the third hour", meaning 9 am. But in John, it was "the sixth hour" (12 noon) when he was turned over by Pilate. Again, there appears to be a theological reason for the change: Passover lambs were normally slaughtered in the afternoon.

Comment: Finally an answer that takes the text at face value.

Comment: I'm a little confused about the times:  *"...The animal was slain on the eve of the Passover, on the afternoon of the 14th of Nisan, after the Tamid sacrifice had been killed, i.e., at three o'clock, or, in case the eve of the Passover fell on Friday, at two..."* http://jewishencyclopedia.com/articles/11934-passover-sacrifice#anchor1 Why is the sixth hour more theologically significant?

Answer (score 1):

I've just joined so I can't comment but colboynik's answer on April 26, 2019, at 17:56 is perfect.
Here are some points of confusion that might prevent people from following his answer:

1. There was a sect that had the Passover supper a day before the Pharisees had it. This is how Jesus had the Passover supper with his disciples while the Pharisees killed the Passover lamb the next day for the formal Passover supper.
2. The day after the formal Passover supper is a high sabbath, the Day of Unleavened bread. So whatever day of the week Jesus was crucified on, the next day was a high sabbath.
3. παρασκευή ([paraskeué](https://www.blueletterbible.org/lexicon/g3904/kjv/tr/0-1/)) means "day of preparation" before a feast (high sabbath) or 7th-day sabbath; **not** "Friday" regardless of modern usage
4. Mark says that Mary Magdalene and Mary the mother of James had bought spices to anoint Jesus' body. Thought must be given as to when they did this. It is highly unlikely that they did this before or during the crucifixion. But Jesus died just before the high sabbath started, so there was no time to go to the shop after he died, until the day after the high sabbath when the shop re-opened. The day after the weekly sabbath, they arrived at the tomb before sunrise, i.e. before the shops opened. So there must have been a day for shopping before Jesus rose, i.e. before the weekly sabbath, and after he died, i.e. after the high sabbath.
   The following fits:

| Tuesday | Wednesday | Thursday | Friday | Saturday | Sunday |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 13 | 14 | 15 | 16 | 17 | 18 |
| night, day | night, day X | night, day | night, day | night, day | X |
| Traditional Passover (Last supper) | Pharisees' Passover | Unleavened bread | Mary bought spices | Sabbath | Mary came to tomb |

Finally, if you don't agree, I'd be grateful for your feedback as to which facts are clearly wrong and why.

Comment: I think the mention of two distinct Passover observances is crucial. The traditional (true) observance is at night of the fourteenth day; this is how Jesus observed it. There was a home-kept observance and a temple-kept observance by the priests in the late afternoon of the fourteenth of the first month. In other words, Jesus kept it as Abib 14 began, while the priests kept it as Abib 14 ended.

Answer (score 0):

Jesus Christ was crucified on the day of preparation for the First Day of Unleavened Bread, and it was not the sixth day of the week (which we call Friday).

Passover **was supposed to be celebrated** at the evening of the 14th of Nisan and the First Day of Unleavened Bread followed on the next evening (the 15th).

Leviticus 23:4-8 (YLT)

> ...
>
> 'These are appointed seasons of Jehovah, holy convocations, which ye proclaim in their appointed seasons:
>
> in the first month, **on the fourteenth of the month**, between the evenings, **is the passover to Jehovah**;
>
> and on the **fifteenth day of this month is the feast of unleavened things to Jehovah**; seven days unleavened things ye do eat;
>
> **on the first day ye have a holy convocation, ye do no servile work**;
>
> and ye have brought near a fire-offering to Jehovah seven days; in the seventh day is a holy convocation; ye do no servile work.'

Some of the confusion stems from the fact that the Jews were celebrating passover *on the wrong day*. They jammed it into the start of the First Day of Unleavened Bread on the 15th of Nissan.

You can see this in some of the passages John wrote.

John 2:13

> ...
>
> And the **passover of the Jews** was nigh, and Jesus went up to Jerusalem,
>
> ...

John 6:4

> ...
>
> and the **passover was nigh, the feast of the Jews**.
>
> ...

John 11:55

> ...
>
> And the **passover of the Jews** was nigh, and many went up to Jerusalem out of the country before the passover, that they might purify themselves;
>
> ...

John 18:39

> ...
>
> ... and ye have a custom that I shall release to you one in the passover [the Jews' passover - **remember Jesus Christ and his disciples had already celebrated passover the previous evening**]; will ye, therefore, that I shall release to you the king of the Jews?'
>
> ...

John 19:14

> ...
>
> and it was the preparation of the passover [the Jews' passover - **again, Jesus Christ and his disciples had celebrated passover the previous evening**], and as it were the sixth hour, and he saith to the Jews, 'Lo, your king!'
>
> ...

So even though the Jews were preparing for what they called the passover, they had really already missed it by a day. The period of time they were preparing for was the First Day of Unleavened Bread, even though they called it Passover.

Also, the Passover is not even technically a sabbath. There is no command to rest on that day. The word *sabbath* means rest. "Sabbath rest" is redundant. The command to observe the First Day of Unleavened Bread does come with a command to rest - it is a sabbath.

Read Leviticus 23:6-7 again:

> ...
>
> and on the fifteenth day of this month is the feast of unleavened things to Jehovah; seven days unleavened things ye do eat;
>
> on the first day ye have a holy convocation, **ye do no servile work** [i.e. rest, it is a sabbath];
>
> ...

So the day the Jews were preparing for was definitely an annual sabbath regardless of what they called it. **However, the day Jesus Christ was crucified and also the day of preparation we are considering could not have been the day before the 7th day of the week (which we call Friday) if we assert the resurrection took place on Sunday. Jesus Christ himself said he would be dead for 3 days and 3 nights**.

Matthew 12:39

> ...
>
> And he answering said to them, 'A generation, evil and adulterous, doth seek a sign, and a sign shall not be given to it, except the sign of Jonah the prophet;
>
> for, **as Jonah was in the belly of the fish three days and three nights, so shall the Son of Man be in the heart of the earth three days and three nights.**
>
> ...

Mark 16:4

> ...
>
> 'A generation evil and adulterous doth seek a sign, and a sign shall not be given to it, except the sign of Jonah the prophet;' and having left them he went away.
>
> ...

Luke 11:29-30

> ...
>
> And the multitudes crowding together upon him, he began to say, 'This generation is evil, a sign it doth seek after, and a sign shall not be given to it, except the sign of Jonah the prophet,
>
> for as Jonah became a sign to the Ninevites, so also shall the Son of Man be to this generation.
>
> ...

John 2:19-23

> ...
>
> And he answering said to them, 'A generation, evil and adulterous, doth seek a sign, and a sign shall not be given to it, except the sign of Jonah the prophet;
>
> for, **as Jonah was in the belly of the fish three days and three nights, so shall the Son of Man be in the heart of the earth three days and three nights.**
>
> 'Men of Nineveh shall stand up in the judgment with this generation, and shall condemn it, for they reformed at the proclamation of Jonah, and lo, a greater than Jonah here!
>
> ...

Here is what the book of Jonah says about the length of time Jonah was in the belly of the fish - just to be complete.

Jonah 1:17

> ...
>
> And Jehovah appointeth a great fish to swallow up Jonah, and Jonah is in the bowels of the fish *three days* **and three nights**.

This length of time that Jesus Christ would be in the ground was the **only piece of proof** He gave to show He was who He said He was.

John 20:1 (CSB)

> **On the first day of the week Mary Magdalene came to the tomb early, while it was still dark.** She saw that the stone had been removed from the tomb.
>
> ...

You might (*might*) be able to argue that the span of time from Friday to Sunday was three *days* (even though you can't even count the day part of Sunday since it was still dark when Mary made it to the tomb and Jesus was already resurrected by that point in time), but there is *no way* to get three nights out of that interval.

So to answer your question more succintly...
Jesus Christ was crucified on the preparation of a particular annual sabbath day which the Jews called the Passover but Leviticus calls the First Day of Unleavened Bread (the Jews missed Passover by a day). It is possible for the First Day of Unleavened Bread (15th of Nisan) to fall on a weekly sabbath, but in this year that Christ was crucified, the First Day of Unleavened Bread (15th of Nisan) did not fall on a weekly sabbath. The day the Jews were preparing for was not the 7th day of the week (which we call Saturday), and the day on which they were making the preparations was not on the sixth day of the week (which we call Friday).

Edit:

To whoever downvoted this answer - at least leave a comment explaining why. Jesus Christ celebrated the Passover the evening before the day being called the preparation for the Passover. This answer is the only one so far that addresses this inconsistency.

Answer (score 0):

The Passover is a Sabbath regardless of which day it fall on. So, the answer is, "both".

See, [High Holy Days, Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High_Holy_Days).

Answer (score -2):

Most answers to this question will be based on the presumption that the Crucifixion was on a Friday.  Using the Bible to support what one already believes is known as *eisegesis*.

If we drop as many preconceived ideas as possible, and look only at what the Bible says, and what history says about the context of the times, we can deduce a different, and perhaps more reliable, idea of the situation.  That is known as *exegesis*.

I recently posted a more detailed explanation of a similar question, [Was there a special Sabbath in addition to Passover when Jesus was crucified?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/63049/was-there-a-special-sabbath-in-addition-to-passover-when-jesus-was-crucified/69547#69547) in Christianity.SE.  I'll summarize it here:

The main evidence (assuming Scripture must be consistent) is:

> We know from Mark 16:1 ("*when the sabbath was past [they] bought sweet spices*") and Luke 23:56 ("*[they] prepared spices and ointments and rested the sabbath day*"), that there were two sabbaths shortly after Jesus's crucifixion. The women waited until after the high sabbath to buy and prepare spices the next day, and then waited until after the normal weekly sabbath to take them to the tomb.

And the conclusion is:

> That means that:
>
> - The weekly sabbath was on Saturday.
> - The spices were bought and prepared the day before, on Friday.
> - The high holiday sabbath was the day before, on Thursday.
> - The Day of Preparation was the day before, on Wednesday.

It contradicts tradition, but if the Bible isn't going to contradict itself, Jesus must have been crucified on the Day of Preparation for the annual Passover sabbath, not on the day of preparation for the weekly Sabbath.

Comment: If Jesus rightly ate the passover on Tuesday, and was crucified on Wednesday, that is, on the first day of the feast of unleavened bread, that would make Thursday, the second day of the feast, to have been essentially called a high holy day for no reason. The argument you make is also based on one interpretation of Mark 16:1, that there must have been two sabbaths since they couldn't have bought spices both before and after the sabbath; yet this is in fact possible, but more probable that Mark 16:1's aorist tense referred to their purchase on Friday.

Comment: You are assuming that "the last supper" was the official Passover meal.  It wasn't.  That happened the following evening, following the "preparation" for it.

Comment: Disagree completely -  Luke 22:15.

Comment: You could make you case sound more compelling if you find some to agree with you among the ante Nicaean fathers.

Comment: Further, how does one reconcile the reference in Luke 24:22 where Cleopas and his friend said, on Sunday evening, it was the third day since Jesus’ trial and crucifixion?  If Jesus had been crucified in Tuesday, Sunday would be the fifth day!

Comment: @RayButterworth, Mark 14:14-16 make it pretty clear "the last supper" was the official Passover meal.

Comment: Correct - but Jesus was still the Passover Lamb John 1:29 1 Cor 5:7.  If that is true, Jesus had to have the Passover the previous day so that he could die on time at Passover.

Comment: The days start at evening. He observed Passover on the evening of Nisan 14 (like Leviticus 23 commanded). He did not sleep the night of the 14th because he was taken into custody and then he died during the day part of Nisan 14. After he was crucified, the Jews were in a hurry to bury him before the evening of the 15th came because they thought that is when passover was supposed to be observed. Even though they called that night passover, it was really the start of the First Day of Unleavened Bread. They still celebrate passover on the evening of the 15th today, even against Leviticus 23.

Comment: Even if he had the passover early so he could "die on time", he still died too early.

Comment: @Mac'sMusings says "_Cleopas and his friend said, on Sunday evening, it was the third day since Jesus’ trial and crucifixion_".   Actually it says "_since_ these things _were done_", not necessarily the crucifixion.  Mat 27:62-64 says "_Now the next day, that followed the day of the preparation, the chief priests and Pharisees came together unto Pilate … that the sepulchre be made sure until the third day_".  Cleopas's could be referring to the sealing of the tomb on Thursday as "these things", so the third day since _that_ would be Sunday.  The third day _since_ Friday is Monday, not Sunday.

Comment: Not quite right.  The immediate referent of "third day" of v21 is v20 - "sentence of death and crucified him."  Third day would necessarily be by inclusive reckoning.  Thus, Sunday is the third day since Friday.

Comment: @Mac'sMusings, if Sunday is the third day since Friday, then Saturday must be the second day since Friday.  So using that terminology, what is "the first day since Friday"?  Most people would say it's Saturday, not Friday.

Comment: Friday is the first day by inclusive reckoning.  See Luke 13:32 'Behold, I cast out demons and perform cures today and tomorrow, and the third day I reach My goal.'

Comment: To take an OT example: in 2 Kings 18:9-10. The siege of Samaria lasted from the fourth to the sixth year of Hezekiah, which is equated with the seventh to the ninth year of Hoshea, and yet the city is said to have been taken “at the end of three years.”

Comment: @Mac'sMusings, "_today and tomorrow, and the third day" is listing three consecutive days; it doesn't correspond to "_the third day_ since these things were done".

Comment: @Mac'sMusings, "_at the end of three years_" makes sense in that context.  But again, it doesn't say "_since_".  I got up at 7:30 this morning and it's now 9:45, which is in the third hour _since_ I got up (not the fourth).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/93078/discussion-between-macs-musings-and-ray-butterworth).

Comment: It can't really be *eisegesis* and *preconceived ideas* given the celebration of the Eucharist on the first day of the week, which we see in Acts 20:7, for instance; unless you're willing to argue that that was also a special Sabbath, as opposed to a usual Saturday.

Comment: @Lucian, in Acts 20:7,  "_upon the first day of the week_" means shortly after sunset on what we would now call Saturday, so it has nothing to do with a Sabbath, weekly or otherwise.  They ate, talked until midnight, and the next morning, Sunday, they departed on their journey.  (Also, interpreting "_came together to break bread_" as celebrating the Eucharist _is_ an example of eisegesis.)

Comment: @RayButterworth: How can *it ha[ve] nothing to do with a Sabbath, weekly or otherwise,* when the very expression, in Greek, reads *in the first of the Sabbath* ? And how can it be *eisegesis*, when the expression in question is known to refer to the Eucharist in at least a few other places ? (Matthew 26:26, Mark 14:22, Luke 24:30-35, Acts 2:42-46, 27:35, 1 Corinthians 10:16).

Comment: @Lucian, "σάββατον" doesn't always mean "sabbath".  It can also mean "week", especially in the context of the "first".  The KJV translates it as "week" 9 times.  "first of the σάββατον" means "first day of the week", and is translated as that in most versions.

Comment: @Lucian, Mat 26:26, Mark 14:22, Luke 24:30, and 1 Cor 10:16 are explicit references to communion, and they don't use the expression "break bread".  The other two, Acts 2:42 and 27:35 simply speak of breaking bread, not of any ceremony.  Unless one already believes that every time they broke bread they were taking communion, one would simply think that they were eating.  To "break bread" is simply to start the meal.    Would talking about "breakfast" indicate that they had just finished a ceremonial fast?  **To a man with a hammer, all problems look like nails.**

Comment: @RayButterworth: There are exactly eleven verses in the entire New Testament containing both words or notions (*break* and *bread*) in their various forms, of which four are a clear reference to the Eucharist. By comparison, the word *eat*, in its various forms, appears 180 times in the same Testament.

Comment: @Ray Butterworth Luke 24:21 states that the day of the resurrection was the third day SINCE the crucifixion. Jews counted their days inclusively so the first day since the crucifixion would be Friday, as strange as that sounds to our ears. "Today is the first day since these things were done". Furthermore, the greek word from where we get the english word "since" is apo. APO is often used inclusively throughout the New Testament. Jude 14 states Enoch was the seventh FROM (apo) Adam. (Genesis 5:1-18). Also, in Matthew 1:17 it states there were 14 generations from (apo) Abraham to David.

Comment: Apo is used inclusively in other places in the New Testament, like "beginning from (apo) the last unto the first" and "from (apo) the sixth hour" and "death reigned from (apo) Adam to Moses" and so forth. See Matthew 20:8, Matthew 27:35 (compare Mark 15:33), Romans 5:14. Also, if you read Acts 10:1-30 carefully, noting verses 1-7 for the first day, verses 9-22 for the second day, 23 for the third day, and 24-30 for the fourth day, you will see even the Romans counted days inclusively. There were four days in the count yet in verse 30 day 1 was the fourth day from (apo) this.