# According to John and Matthew could the last supper included the sacrificial lamb?

Tags: john, matthew

> John 19:31
> Now it was the **day of Preparation**, and the next day was to be a special Sabbath. Because the Jewish leaders did not want the bodies left on the crosses during the Sabbath, they asked **Pilate** to have the legs broken and the bodies taken down.

According to John, the day of Preparation was the day that Jesus was crucified.

> Matthew 26:2
> "As you know, the **Passover is two days away**--and the Son of Man will be handed over to be **crucified**."

> Matthew 26:17
> On the **first day of the Festival of Unleavened Bread**, the disciples came to Jesus and asked, "Where do you want us to make preparations for you to eat the Passover?"

> Matthew 26:65
> Then the high priest tore his clothes and said, "He has spoken blasphemy! Why do we need any more witnesses? Look, now you have heard the blasphemy.

> Matthew 27:62
> The next day, the one **after Preparation Day**, the chief priests and Pharisees assembled before **Pilate**.

According to Matthew, Preparation Day was the day before Pilate's gave permission to secure the tomb. Then Preparation Day was the day Jesus was crucified and they ate the last supper on the day before the Preparation Day. Jesus and his disciples could not have eaten the sacrificial lamb in the last supper.

Comment: [ John ] contains other errors pertaining to the Festivals, such as [ John 6:4 ] the random Pesach that Yeshua avoided ( or the inserted Pesach that never happened ).

Comment: As with all of these instances, where (apparently, because of our limited knowledge) we suppose a 'discrepancy', there is an explanation. On this site, over the past nine years or so, all of these 'discrepancies' have been done to death in multiple questions and answers. You just need to check them. This one is answered in several questions, one of them being this one -------> [..Day of Preparation ... Sabbath....Passover](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/40384/was-the-day-when-jesus-died-a-day-of-preparation-for-a-regular-sabbath-for-pass).

Comment: I don’t know that this site can answer the question “Can both passages be inspired by God?” But we could certainly address the discrepancy. I personally think it’s a clear contradiction but that it’s intentional because John is pointing to Jesus as the Lamb of God who takes away the sin of world (cf. Jn. 1:29), having him condemned to death when the Passover lambs are being slaughtered in the temple.

Comment: The assertion about Matt 27:62 in the question is misleading. While one could describe the Preparation Day as the day before Pilate's judgement, it was not the day before Pilate's judgement about Jesus' execution. Jesus was already executed and buried on the previous day (i.e., on the Preparation Day)! Instead, in Matt 27:62, the Preparation Day was the day before Pilate's judgement about securing the tomb (vv. 65–66). There is no contradiction here.

Answer (score 0):

It isn't the day of preparation, it's the day of concoction.

3-15 is grape harvest and the New wine festival. The παρα-σκευή of the Passover. The day of παρα-sychar (wine concoction).

https://www.blueletterbible.org/lang/lexicon/lexicon.cfm?Strongs=G3904&t=KJV